# Do unique passive buffs from different items stack? 

Tags: league-of-legends

Many items have UNIQUE Passive: Some Description as a part of their description.  I understand that UNIQUE implies that you cannot have 2 of the same item with the same effect.

What I am not sure about and haven't found information about is whether you can stack SIMILAR UNIQUE Passives.

Boots, for instance, may have Increased Movement Speed 2, or Increased Movement Speed 3 (among other things) as UNIQUE Passives.  Does that mean that I can wear both and receive the benefits of both, since they are not identical?  (2 vs 3)  Or since they affect the same stat, do they not stack with each other?

I haven't been able to find clarification on that point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Boots are a specific case.  You can't have more than one movement buff from any kinds of boots at all.

As for other items with UNIQUE passives, as long as you don't have the exact same item, they all stack on top of each other.

Apparently, there are other exceptions as well.  From the [wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Unique):

> Unique effects that do not cumulate among differents items include Movement Speed effects from boots (only the best effect applies), proc effect of  Sheen, Lich Bane and Trinity Force, and the mana gained from Tear of the Goddess, Manamune and Archangel's Staff.

Comment: I always thought it was based on the stat. So that, for example, Ionian Boots of Lucidity didn't stack with other cooldown reduction effects that were UNIQUE, with the exception of the Soul Shroud which is a cooldown reduction *aura*. Hm... this changes things a fair amount...

Comment: Strix is right, they are only unique to that item specifically.

Comment: @GraceNote: I'm pretty sure that upgrades of the same item don't stack either. So, for example, the mana bonuses from Tear of the Goddess, Archangel Staff, and Manamune don't stack.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that Uniques are pretty much named now so any UNIQUE Passive with the same name doesn't stack (This basically states what has already been mentioned but in simpler terms).

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that any champion with a unique friendly aura item (Zeke's Herald, Will of the Ancients) can additionally receive that aura from another champion. This is why double Will of the Ancients is so strong and common, the owners of those items get double the effects of the buff when near each other.

http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Aura